# Two routes with the same name on production. (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, spree

I've got a ruby 2.4.0, rails 5.0.2, spree 3.2 app.
I tried to create a custom admin report for viewing all my inventory products. Ugly for now but works perfectly on development, unlike production where app crashes. 
When running `heroku run rails c` it says `You may have defined two routes with the same name using the`:as`option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming.`

Following, everything added after the last successful commit, by expected relevance:

## routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: '/'
  MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
      Spree::Core::Engine.routes.append do
        get '/admin/reports/stock_per_location' => 'admin/reports#stock_per_location', as: 'stock_per_location_admin_reports'
      end
    end
end
```

## production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true

  config.eager_load = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = true

  config.log_level = :debug

  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new


  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false


  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
      access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
      url: ENV.fetch("BUCKET_URL"),
    }
  }

end
```

## reports_controller_decorator.rb

```
require_dependency 'spree/admin/reports_controller'

Spree::Admin::ReportsController.class_eval do
  add_available_report! :stock_per_location

  def stock_per_location
    @stock_locations = Spree::StockLocation.all
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparently creating the routes directly isn't supported by the latest version of Spree, changed my routes.rb and it worked fine.

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
      Spree::Core::Engine.routes.append do
        #causing troubles on production: get '/admin/reports/stock_per_location' => 'admin/reports#stock_per_location', as: 'stock_per_location_admin_reports', only: [:index]
        namespace :admin do
        resources :reports, only: [:index] do
          collection do
            get :stock_per_location
            #post :total_sales_of_each_product
          end
        end
      end
    end
end
```